# Custom JS text area in customizer is being formatted wrong in document

Tags: javascript, theme-customizer, esc-textarea

I have created a wordpress theme, in the wordpress theme customizer I have added a couple of text areas where a user can input their own CSS or JS to be added to the head.

The placement of the text area is fine, i.e. when a user adds code it is displayed on the right place in the page, however it is being formatted differently.

For example, I add the following code to one of the textareas:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('full_page').css('min-height',($(window).height()-195));  
});
```

And in my theme it is outputted like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(&#039;full_page&#039;).css(&#039;min-height&#039;,($(window).height()-195));  
});
```

As you can see, the `'` is being replaced with `&#039;`

Here is the code in my customizer.php file to create the text area:

```
$controls[] = array(
        'type'     => 'textarea',
        'setting'  => 'js',
        'label'    => __( 'Custom JS', 'skizzar_bootstrap' ),
        'subtitle' => __( 'You can write your custom JavaScript/jQuery here. The code will be included in a script tag appended to the top of the page.', 'skizzar_bootstrap' ),
        'section'  => 'advanced',
        'priority' => 6,
        'default'  => '',
    );
```

To output in my theme I am using:

```
<script><php echo get_theme_mod('js'); ?></script>
```

Is there a way to stop this formatting from happening?

Comment: What's your code for outputting the values of these settings?

Comment: @TheDeadMedic just added

Comment: Can you post the code that registers `$controls` with the customize API?

Answer (score 1):

@sam-skirrow just posting here what we did to fix this...

WordPress 4.1 requires us to use a `sanitize_callback` filter when creating settings for the customizer (with good reason).
Since you're using the [kirki](http://kirki.org) framework to create these customizer settings, [kirki detects that this is a textarea field and so it automatically applies the `esc_textarea` filter](https://github.com/aristath/kirki/blob/0aa5765352e9005347783ceaf1f4a962dfdb3b5c/includes/class-Kirki_Settings.php#L90-L91).

However, [you can override this callback and use your own](https://github.com/aristath/kirki/blob/0aa5765352e9005347783ceaf1f4a962dfdb3b5c/includes/class-Kirki_Settings.php#L110) when declaring the field, so all that we needed to do in order to fix this was add a js sanitization calback there instead of the `esc_textarea`.